# Angular - spy on method inside subscribe block

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-test

I have a component with the following ngOnInit() method:

```
ngOnInit() {
  combineLatest([
    this.observable1,
    this.observable2
  ])
  .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
  .subscribe(([data1, data2]) => {
    this.processData(data1, data2);
  });
}
```

I want to write a test to verify that the processData() method is called.

I tried something like this:

```
it('should call processData', ()=> {
   ... make sure each observable1 and observable2 will emit a value
   spyOn(component, 'processData');
   fixture.detectChanges();
   expect(component.processData).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

`expect(component.processData).toHaveBeenCalled()` will always return false, it doesn't seem to wait until both observables emit a value.

My question is how to test such code? How to test that a method was called inside a subscribe function of an async rxjs operator?

Comment: You'll most likely have to stub the observables as well. It may not work now because they're emitting values asynchronously. Did you consider using something like `spyOn(comp, 'observable1').and.returnValue(of('dummy data'))` ?

Answer (score 0):

The first question is what do `this.observable1` and `this.observable2` do?

To trigger `this.processData` both of them should emit at least once.
Might you great if you could share more code of the test and how `observable1` and `observable2` are created.

I would suggest to change the test to the next style

```js
it('should call processData', ()=> {
   // firstly set the spy
   spyOn(component, 'processData');

   // secondly we need to fake our observables
   component.observable1 = of(1);
   component.observable2 = of(2);

   // now we trigger the flow
   component.ngOnInit();

   // clean up
   component.unsubscribe$.next();
   component.unsubscribe$.complete();

   // assertions
   expect(component.processData).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1, 2);
}));
```